# Is there a way to add a navigation route to list in Flutter/Dart?

Tags: flutter, dart

I am new to Flutter/Dart but I have tried a few ways to add a navigation route to a list that I assign to a grid view. It may not be the most efficient way to do it but it was the first thing that came to mind. I wanted to add an InkWell to the card and have the navigation routes passed that way. Other than that the only other solution I can think of is creating an OnTap function that iterates through the list. Currently the nav list choice is giving me an error that says that a 'future object can't be assigned to a parameter type of Navigator', which I get because it is a constant. But I tried it a few other ways and  got similar results. What am I doing wrong with my current configuration and is there a better/more efficient solution?

**Here is my list of choices:**

```
class Choice {
  const Choice({this.title, this.icon, this.nav});
  final String title;
  final IconData icon;
  final Navigator nav;
}

const List<Choice> choices = const <Choice>[
  const Choice(title: 'Timer', icon: Icons.timer, nav: Navigator.pushNamed(context, TestConfirmation.id)),
  const Choice(title: 'Seating Chart', icon: Icons.event_seat),
  const Choice(title: 'Random', icon: Icons.shuffle),
  const Choice(title: 'Group Maker', icon: Icons.group_add),
  const Choice(title: 'Noise Monitor', icon: Icons.hearing),
  const Choice(title: 'Assign Tasks', icon: Icons.assignment_ind),
  const Choice(title: 'Survey', icon: Icons.rate_review),
  const Choice(title: 'Permission Slips', icon: Icons.assignment),
  const Choice(title: 'Lesson Plans', icon: Icons.local_library),
  const Choice(title: 'Attendance', icon: Icons.schedule),
  const Choice(title: 'Gradebook', icon: Icons.insert_chart)
];
```

**Here is my Card:**

```
class ChoiceCard extends StatelessWidget {
  const ChoiceCard({Key key, this.choice}) : super(key: key);
  final Choice choice;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final TextStyle textStyle = Theme.of(context).textTheme.subhead;
    return Card(
        color: Colors.white,
        child: InkWell(
          //onTap: choice.navigation,
          child: Center(
            child: Column(
                mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                children: <Widget>[
                  Expanded(
                      child: Icon(choice.icon,
                          size: 90.0, color: textStyle.color)),
                  Text(choice.title, style: textStyle),
                ]),
          ),
        ));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve it by using GenerateRoute and building a separate route class. I am posting the solution with a smaller data set in case someone runs into a similar question in the future.

**Choice Class:**

```
class Choice {
  const Choice({this.title, this.icon, this.nav});
  final String title;
  final IconData icon;
  final String nav;
}

const List<Choice> choices = const <Choice>[
  const Choice(title: 'Timer', icon: Icons.timer, nav: timer),
  const Choice(
      title: 'Seating Chart', icon: Icons.event_seat, nav: seatingChart),
  const Choice(title: 'Random', icon: Icons.shuffle, nav: randomPicker),
  const Choice(title: 'Group Maker', icon: Icons.group_add, nav: groupMaker),
];
```

**ChoiceCard Class:**

```
class ChoiceCard extends StatelessWidget {
  const ChoiceCard({Key key, this.choice}) : super(key: key);
  final Choice choice;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final TextStyle textStyle = Theme.of(context).textTheme.subhead;
    return Card(
        color: Colors.white,
        child: InkWell(
          onTap: () {
            Navigator.pushNamed(context, choice.nav);
          },
          child: Center(
            child: Column(
                mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                children: <Widget>[
                  Expanded(
                    child:
                        Icon(choice.icon, size: 90.0, color: textStyle.color),
                  ),
                  Text(choice.title, style: textStyle),
                ]),
          ),
        ));
  }
}
```

**Router Class:**

```
class Router {
  static Route<dynamic> generateRoute(RouteSettings settings) {
    switch (settings.name) {
      case assignTasks:
        return MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_) => AssignTasks());
      case attendance:
        return MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_) => Attendance());
      case gradeBook:
        return MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_) => GradeBook());
      case groupMaker:
        return MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_) => GroupMaker());
            default:
        return MaterialPageRoute(
            builder: (_) => Scaffold(
                  body: Center(
                      child: Text('No route defined for ${settings.name}')),
                ));
    }
  }
}

//Dynamic Routes for generating navigation
const String assignTasks = AssignTasks.id;
const String attendance = ProfileForm.id;
const String gradeBook = ClassProfile.id;
const String groupMaker = GroupMaker.id;
```